# Using React and Redux Hooks, why is my action not firing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Edit: SOLVED! Please see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59077964/8234403).

I want my `Blog` component to fire the `fetchBlog` action creator every time the browser requests its URL, be it via a link or a refresh. I'd like to do it with the React `useEffect` Hook and with the React-Redux `useDispatch` and `useSelector` Hooks. However, my action only fires when following the link to the page; I do not understand why, even after reading several explanations (like [the official docs](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch)).

Here is the code:

```js
// Everything duly imported, or else VSC would yell at me

export default function Blog() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
    // slug is set here with useSelector, this always works
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchBlog(slug))
  }, [slug, dispatch]);
  const blog = useSelector((state) => state.blogs[0]);
    // return renders the blog information from the blog constant
    // since the action does not fire, blog is undefined because state.blogs is an empty array
}
```

I know that, on refresh, `fetchBlog` does not fire because of Redux DevTools and also because I put a `debugger` there. (And the back-end logs don't show the request coming in.) The action creator itself and the reducer must be working; if they weren't, the page would not load correctly when visited through a link.

Edit: I have determined `useSelector` and `useDispatch` are not the root cause of the problem, as changing the code to use `connect` with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` gives the same result. The issue seems to be with `useEffect`.

Comment: Is the component unmounted, maybe that's the reason it doesn't fire afterwards?

Comment: I don't think it is unmounted, as I still get an error: the action doesn't fire, so `state.blogs` is an empty array, so `data` is undefined, so reading `blog.title` in the JSX part throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

But I'm not very confident in this - how can I be 100% positive the component is unmounted? What could unmount it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear to me where the slug comes from.
In theory `useEffect` runs after every render. In case of multiple parameters it will run the callback when one of the array parameters passed in the second argument changes.

Either create a `useEffect` with empty array as second argument to run it 'once' (e.g. when you refresh) or check the slug value.

Edits after checking the repo:

- It's not going to work because useEffect is run AFTER the render (which was included in my answer although someone downvoted it). Dispatching the call will only happen after, or not at all if the exception was thrown before (in this case a nullpointer).
- You can get the slug from react-router with `match`, may be handy for you to know.

  ```
  export default function Blog({ match }) {
      const slug = match.params.slug;
  etc
  ```
- The git repo shows how dispatch as is added as array parameter to `useEffect`, which is not necessary.

Comment: I think the problem with that is that the component may not always unmount before mounting again with a new slug. So op would want to keep the second argument of use effect as is.

Comment: @pizza-r0b I don't know why you speak of unmount, as the user clearly speaks about a refresh of the page, which means all components are reloaded.

Comment: "be it via a link or a refresh"

Comment: "However, my action only fires when following the link to the page" + "I know that, on refresh, fetchBlog does not fire"

Comment: Thank you for your input! I do know that the slug is okay, I can log it and it shows up okay.

I changed the code so that the callback passed to `useEffect` both calls `fetchBlog` and returns the same call. That way, the return value would be called on unmounting. This does not solve the issue.

I also removed the slug from the deps array, as well as removing the array itself, and all that got me was a warning that they were missing.

Comment: @brunoparga Scope wise, dispatch should not be undefined, otherwise you need to check why it is undefined. You should not have a return value in useEffect, just calling the dispatch method should be sufficient. An empty array should work if dispatch is defined. There really shouldn't be need to pass it in the array either as it's just a function that was declared in the outer scope.

Comment: None of these are undefined when `useEffect` gets called (when following the link). I don't get why `useEffect` itself doesn't fire when refreshing the page.

Comment: Does the component code get called at all when you refresh? If you have an empty array in useeffect, you should really check why dispatch is undefined, it shouldn’t be. And only the slug parameter should be passed.

Comment: `dispatch` is not undefined, it is what it should be. The only thing that should be defined but isn't is `data`. I can log `dispatch`, `fetchBlog` and `slug` outside of `useEffect` and their values show up okay. I can also log them inside of `useEffect`, but they only show in the original render, since the core issue is that `useEffect` is not working on refresh.

The component does get called, I know it because I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined` from the JSX that gets returned from the component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203199/discussion-between-trace-and-brunoparga).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you are returning the call to dispatch. Functions returned from useEffect are clean up functions, so I don't think this would run on mount, or update - only before unmount. Try this:

```js
export default function Blog() {
  // ...
  // Don't return from useEffect. Just call dispatch within the body.
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchBlog(slug);
  }, [slug, dispatch]);
  // ...

}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect

Comment: You're correct that I shouldn't be returning from within `useEffect`, thank you. Unfortunately, that still does not solve the issue - `useEffect` itself is not being triggered on refresh. Even so, I appreciate your input.

Comment: @brunoparga Try running it with an empty array, even if it still doesn't work, you can exclude the possibility that the problem lies with the parameters that are passed via the useEffect array.

Comment: That gives me `Line 12:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch' and 'slug'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` on the console.

Comment: @brunoparga sorry I think there was an extra parenthesis. Can you post the updated code?

Comment: @brunoparga that looks like an eslint error. you could put `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` above the offending line to disable it and see if it works. Why do you need to pass dispatch into the useEffect array? I'm not sure you do. And where does slug come from? It doesn't look explicitly defined. I think it needs to be defined in the component an accessible in the hook body.

Comment: Changing the deps array does not change the result, and what should be in there, as per React Hooks docs, is often not what we would expect (I agree it is not obvious why `dispatch` belongs).

I can log `slug` just fine, I know for sure that is not the problem. The issue is mainly: why isn't the effect firing?

Comment: Unfortunately I would need more code to assist you. If you have a repo I can look at I can probably help debug.

Comment: Thank you, I'd really appreciate that. Here: https://github.com/brunoparga/front-end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203198/discussion-between-brunoparga-and-pizza-r0b).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to clarify what the issue was, which @Trace guided me to finding.

`useEffect` wasn't being called on refresh because it gets called *after* the component renders/returns. When refreshing, the state - including the blog data - is lost; instead of returning, a `TypeError` is thrown because `data.title` doesn't exist. So `useEffect` never gets the chance of being called and fetch the blog's content.

The solution to that goes like this:

```js
export default function Blog() {
  // ...
  useEffect(/* ... */)
  const blog = useSelector((state) => state.blogs[0]);
  if (!blog) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }
  // return actual blog contents here
}
```

So now `fetchBlog` does get called, updating `blog` and rendering the content.

Comment: This will get an invalid hook call. `useSelector` hook should be called at the component  body level?